# C# Winform Radio button behavior

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button

I have 2 radio buttons calling 2 methods on `_CheckedChanged` event

```
private void manual_radioBtn_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendDataManual();
        }

private void auto_radioBtn_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendDataAuto();
        }
```

Now when I check the radiobutton, doesn't matter which one, both functions are being  triggered.

When I check `manual_radioBtn`, both **SendDataManual()** & **SendDataAuto()** are being called and if I check
`auto_radioBtn` also, both **SendDataManual()** & **SendDataAuto()** are being called.

I know this behaviour won't occur if am using a `Click` event rather than `CheckedChanged`. But isn't `CheckedChanged` the default even for radiobutton.

Is this a normal behavior with radiobuttons or specific behavior when using 2 radiobuttons

What if there are 3 buttons .Will all the methods under the 3 button event trigger at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event name gives away it's purpose - `CheckedChanged` which indicates that the `Checked` state of the `RadioButton` has changed.  It's not stating that `Checked = true` (or otherwise), just that the value of it changed.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checkedchanged), `CheckedChanged`:

> Occurs when the value of the Checked property changes.

One way to handle this is to check the value of the `Checked` property in your code:

```
private void manual_radioBtn_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (manual_radioBtn.Checked)
        SendDataManual();
}

private void auto_radioBtn_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (auto_radioBtn.Checked)
        SendDataAuto();
}
```

My preference would be to handle this in a single function though, something like:

```
private void manual_radioBtn_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendData();
}

private void auto_radioBtn_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendData();
}

private void SendData()
{
    if (manual_radioBtn.Checked)
        SendDataManual();
    else if (auto_radioBtn.Checked)
        SendDataAuto();
}
```

An advantate of using a single function to handle the response to the event is that you only need one event handler for all of the appropriate `CheckedChanged` events, rather than one for each `RadioButton`.  That might not seem important when you have two but imagine you have 20 of them.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be more efficient.